# How do i animate scattered divs to align on pageload

Tags: jquery, layout, scatter

I was browsing for some ideas for a new project and this animation caught my eye [HERE](http://gulfmarcom.com/).

On pre-pageload the boxes are scattered, but after loading the scattered boxes come about and align themselves in their respective positions. This seems to be a complicated jQuery application but i am willing to learn.

Any help would be appreciated please, maybe a link to a tutorial or a starting point?

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/rvtusu89/) is a fiddle to my layout. Can i have all 5 blocks in my layout to animate like the above website?

```
<!--Body-->
<div id="bodyContainer">

    <div id="indexSpotlightContainer">
        SLIDER
    </div>

    <div class="indexBlockDivider"></div>

    <div id="indexBlockContainer1">
        <div class="indexInfoBlock">
            BLOCK1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="indexBlockDivider"></div>

    <div id="indexBlockContainer2">
        BLOCK2
    </div>

    <div class="indexBlockDivider"></div>

    <div id="indexBlockContainer3">
        <div class="indexSpotContainer1">
            BLOCK3
        </div>
        <div class="indexSpotContainer2">
            BLOCK4
        </div>
        <div class="indexSpotContainer3">
            BLOCK5
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!--Body-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, May require adjustments at top `css` block to achieve exact expected effects

Try utilizing [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) , [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) , [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack)

```
// select all elements to animate,
// apply beginning animation style,
// default syle
$("[class^=index], [id^=index]").css({
    "width":"0px",
    "height":"0px",
    "margin":"2px",
    "padding":"2px",
    "float":"left"
})
.filter(function() {
  return /^indexInfoBlock/.test(this.className)
})
.animate({
    width:"964px",
    height:"215px"
}, 5000)
.addBack()
.filter(function() {
  return /^indexBlockDiviver|indexSpotlightContainer/.test(this.id)
})
.animate({
    width:"1024px",
    height:"100px"
}, 5000)   
.addBack()
.filter(function() {
  return /^indexBlockDiviver/.test(this.className)
})
.animate({
    width:"1024px",
    height:"10px"
}, 5000)
.addBack()
.filter(function() {
  return /^indexBlockContainer/.test(this.id)
})
.animate({
    width:"1024px",
    height:"270px"
}, 5000)
.addBack()
.filter(function() {
  return /^indexSpotContainer/.test(this.className)
})
.animate({
    width:"334px",
    height:"270px"
}, 5000);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rvtusu89/2/